# Can I join two Trello accounts together?

Tags: trello

I have boards on two accounts and I was wondering if I can join them together, so I only need to have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, make yourself admins at both accounts for every

- card
- list
- organization
- board

Accept the invitations and then copy the boards over from the account that is not needed to the useful account

Finally you have to close one account, or make it dormant

Comment: Not sure why someone down voted, it works! I just basically invited the active account to everything and closed the account I don't want anymore.

Comment: The official solution is given by Trello here: http://help.trello.com/article/739-merging-multiple-trello-accounts